# CSS percentage width not working

Tags: html, css, navigation, width, percentage

I've been trying to edit the CSS for my website's navbar in order to transform it from having fixed width and height values into percentage values (in order for it to become responsive and work better with different screen sizes). However, when I converted the values, the individual divs didn't correctly size.

There is probably something very simple that I've missed here (seeing as I am a self taught amateur in CSS and HTML), but I couldn't find any solutions here.

This is a [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/turdauko/) of my naviation bar using px, working properly

This is a [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vjhz7o8y/2/) of it after conversion to percentage values for width.

Relevant code (post conversion):

HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="container">
    <div id="menuwrap">
        <ul id="menu">
        <li id="one"><a href="#"><h class="navbartext">one</h></a></li>
        <li id="two"><a href="#"><h class="navbartext">two</h></a></li>
        <li id="three"><a href="#"><h class="navbartext">three</h></a></li>
        <li id="four"><a href="#"><h class="navbartext">four</h></a></li>
        <li id="five"><a href="#"><h class="navbartext">five</h></a></li>
        <li id="six"><a href="#"><h class="navbartext">six</h></a></li>
        <li id="seven"><a href="#"></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
    width:100%;
    height:25px;
    margin:0 auto;
    background:#fff;
}

#menuwrap {
    height:25px;
    width:100%
    position:relative;
    top:25px;
    background:#fff;
}

ul#menu {
    height:25px;
    float:right;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style-type:none;
    background:#44546A;
}

ul#menu li {
    float:left;
}

ul#menu li a {
    display: block;
    width: auto;
    height:25px;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-indent:10px;
    background:#000;
    color:#000;
}

ul#menu li#one a {
    width:16.6%;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

ul#menu li#two a {
    width:16.6%;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

ul#menu li#three a {
    width:16.6%;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

ul#menu li#four a {
    width:16.6%;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

ul#menu li#five a {
    width:16.6%;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

ul#menu li#six a {
    width:17%;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

ul#menu li#seven a {
    width: 49px;
    height: 49px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 25px;
    -moz-border-radius: 25px;
    border-radius: 25px; 
    background-color:#000;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #fff;
    position:relative;
    top: -17.5px;
    left:88%;
    z-index:2;
}

ul#menu li class.a
{
width:208px;
margin:0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `width: 100%;` to `ul#menu`.

Check it out here: https://jsfiddle.net/vjhz7o8y/5/.

Also, avoid using the same `id` for multiple elements, use `class` instead.

```
ul#menu {
    height:25px;
    width:100%;
    float:right;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style-type:none;
    background:#44546A;
}
```

Comment: Adding this doesn't completely fix my problem, as the links on the navigation bar are still not expanding to their correct portions (approximately (100/6)% each). 
Also, which elements have I used id in place of class? 
Thanks.

Comment: You used four circles with the same id `circle`. Do you want the circle to be displayed to the far left side?

Answer (score 0):

My web-design book, Murach's HTML5 and CSS3 3rd edition says to use slickNav for a responsive menu. It is a Javascript plugin. **Also**, I have just fixed my problem sort of. I was attempting to size the blocked  elements when I should have been sizing their *containers*. Here is some sample code

```
nav {width:100%;}

nav #nav_menu {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0%;
    margin: 0%;
}

 #nav_menu > li {
    float: left;
    width:20%;
    max-width: 190px;
}
```

Hope this helps.